# linux add a file to an existing file

Tags: linux, file, append, cat

I have a bash script that runs through several folders and processes the files' content. The resulting file, newFile I want to append to a file in another folder. This file has the same name (newFile). So, I do this

```
cat $outfn1 >> /newFolder/newFile
```

But this does not work. The newFile is surely moved to the newFolder. However, it is not appended to the old version of the newFile, which is what I would like it to do. It replaces the old version.

Is there any way around this one?
Thank you.

jd

Comment: Grrr.  There are no "folders" in a file system.  There are directories.  Folders contain files, directories do not.  Directories contains names of files.  A folder is an abstraction of the gui.

Comment: I tested `cat $outfn1 >> /newFolder/newFile` and it works, it appends the content of the new file to older version of the new file.